# Background Image on a List Item

Tags: css, xhtml

Think its a simple one.

I am working on a site.
The design is [here](http://www.solumac.co.uk/test/code/home.jpg)

I've hit a little snag as to how to do the footer strategy | management | recovery.

As each item has a background image associated with it, How do I position the background image so that it is at the very bottom of the list item. I've tried `background: bottom center;`

But it just seems to push it behind.

Any help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I've used some random image I found of  a red square, this could just as easily be your image.

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/5NC7L/</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/5NC7L/1/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    padding: 0 0 50px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('http://www.martin.com/color/small/red305.1.gif') no-repeat bottom center;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that second one will do it nicely. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
a.strategy   { border-bottom: 44px solid #CC7A16;}
a.management { border-bottom: 44px solid #00718C;}
a.recovery   { border-bottom: 44px solid #954256;}
```